# Wxpython: saving all scrolledpanel as an image

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to save the whole panel as an image file, but my panel is scrolledpanel. Following is code:

```
x, y = self.Canvas.GetClientSize()
source = wx.ClientDC(self.Canvas)
memory = wx.MemoryDC()
bitmap = wx.Bitmap( x, y, -1 )
memory.SelectObject( bitmap )
memory.Blit(0, 0, x, y, source, 0, 0)
bitmap.SaveFile("test.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP )
memory.SelectObject( wx.NullBitmap)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UdPd.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6seM0.jpg

But when saving as an image file, the bitmap cannot show all panel.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jIrt.jpg
How to solve this problem? Could you please give me some suggestion for revising my code?

Comment: Arguably, if you can not see it, it will not be included in your bitmap, which afterall is just a representation of the pixels on your display.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how could I do to save the whole panel? or how could I revise my code?